# C: Node Removal

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I'm really struggling with this exercise about linked lists and node removal.

Basically, DNA sequences are said to be complementary when each base in one sequence has the corresponding complement in the other sequence at the same position. Base A bonds with T, and base C bonds with G. For example, the sequences ACGT and TGCA are complementary.

I have to implement a function which takes two linked lists: the first is the original DNA and the second is the edit sequence. The function must apply the edit method described earlier and return the new list.

For instance, we've got "A C G T A G A C G T T C T A" as the original DNA sequence and "G C A" as the bonding sequence. G matches with C, C matches with G and A matches with T (and vice-versa). Therefore, "C G T" is "G C A"'s reflex. Then we have to remove "C", "G" and T", following this exact order, from the original DNA sequence, which turns out to be the expected result stated below.

Also, two things: 1. I must ignore any subsequent matches generated as a result of any node removals. 2. I cannot use any headers besides stdlib.h and functions such as malloc() or calloc(). I am only allowed to use free().

**Input:**

```
A C G T A G A C G T T C T A
G C A
```

**Expected Result:**

```
A A G A T C T A
```

**Actual Result:**

```
A A G A C G T T C T A
```

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how we're getting the expected result.

Comment: Couple of questions. 1) Recursion isn't a natural part of solving this problem. Why did you choose it?  2) What if a deletion creates a new match. For example supose you have CCGTGT with edit string GCA.  After the first deletion you have CGT, which matches again, leaving nothing.  Is the second match allowed?  Or does the search for matches restart _after_ the end of the previous one.

Comment: Hi @ggorlen, we've got "A C G T A G A C G T T C T A" as the original DNA sequence and "G C A" as the bonding sequence. G matches with C, C matches with G and A matches with T (and vice-versa). Therefore, "C G T" is "G C A"'s reflex. Then we have to remove "C", "G" and T", following this exact sequence, from the original DNA sequence, which turns out to be the expected result ("A A G A T C T A"). Sorry if I didn't make myself clear.

Comment: OK, so the algorithm is to take the reflex of the second list, then remove all subsequences of the reflexed second occurring in the first list? It has to match the full subsequence for anything to be removed? It might be good to edit that explanation into the post; comments are temporary. Thanks! (I second that recursion is a poor fit for this; it'll blow the stack on any nontrivial input because it's linear!)

Comment: Hi @Gene, thanks for asking. First question, straight and short: I find the recursive way to be the most simple and "understandable" when it comes to transversing a linked list. Second question: I forgot to mention that I MUST ignore any potential subsequent matches. Just edited. Hope it's clear view now!

Comment: @ggorlen exactly, you can put it in that way. And yes, it has to match the full sequence i. e. in the example above I cannot remove "T C T" or "G T T" from the list even though they might match with one char of the sequence "G C A". I have to take into consideration the order and number of the elements and that's when my auxiliary function comes into action.

Comment: can you share the details of `LinkedNode` structure? I hope it's a practice exercise. Char-Arrays for this scenario serve better.

Comment: Hi @SparKot, sure. Thanks for asking. Just updated the code above with the structure elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have written a code based on your current code for better
communication but I thought it will be simpler not to use the recursion.
Would you please try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LinkedNode {
    char data;
    struct LinkedNode *next;
} LinkedNode;

/*
 * append the node with data at the end of the list
 */
void append(LinkedNode *head, char data)
{
    LinkedNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    LinkedNode *temp = head;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newNode;
}

/*
 * dump the data of the list
 */
void dump(LinkedNode *head)
{
    for (head = head->next; head != NULL; head = head->next) {
        printf("%c ", head->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*
 * generate another list of complimentary sequence
 */
void gencomp(LinkedNode *dest, LinkedNode *src)
{
    char s_data, d_data;
    for (src = src->next; src != NULL; src = src->next) {
        s_data = src->data;
        switch(s_data) {
            case 'A':
                d_data = 'T';
                break;
            case 'T':
                d_data = 'A';
                break;
            case 'C':
                d_data = 'G';
                break;
            case 'G':
                d_data = 'C';
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "unknown base: %c\n", s_data);
                exit(1);
        }
        append(dest, d_data);
    }
}

/*
 * return the pointer to the last element if the subsequences match
 */
LinkedNode *match(LinkedNode *head, LinkedNode *comp)
{
    for (; head != NULL; head = head->next, comp = comp->next) {
        if (head->data != comp->data) {
            return NULL;
        } else if (comp->next == NULL) {
            return head;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

/*
 * search "head" for "comp". If matched, the matched portion is skipped
 * (not freed)
 */
void edit(LinkedNode *head, LinkedNode *comp)
{
    LinkedNode *matched;

    for (; head != NULL; head = head->next) {
        if ((matched = match(head->next, comp->next))) {
            head->next = matched->next;         // skip matched sequence
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char dna_orig[] = "ACGTAGACGTTCTA";
    char dna_bond[] = "GCA";
    int i;

    // generate list of original sequence
    LinkedNode *head = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
    head->next = NULL;
    for (i = 0; dna_orig[i] != 0; i++) {
        append(head, dna_orig[i]);
    }

    // generate list of bonding sequence
    LinkedNode *bond = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
    bond->next = NULL;
    for (i = 0; dna_bond[i] != 0; i++) {
        append(bond, dna_bond[i]);
    }

    // generate list of complementary sequence of bond
    LinkedNode *comp = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
    comp->next = NULL;
    gencomp(comp, bond);

    // edit the original sequence and see the result
    edit(head, comp);
    dump(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A A G A T C T A
```

- I have created a list of complementary sequence of the bonding sequence
  to make the searching easy.
- The code is inefficient so far because it uses repeated linear search in the list.
- I had to include <stdio.h> for the printing purpose.

**[Edit]**
When freeing the skipped nodes, we cannot free them in the forward order
from head to tail, because the link to the next node is lost as soon as
the first node is freed. Then we can make use of *recursion* to free them
in the reverse order. Here is the function to free the skipped nodes:

```
void freenodes(LinkedNode *head, LinkedNode *tail)
{
    if (head->next == tail) {                   // the last node to remove
        free(head);
        return;
    }
    freenodes(head->next, tail);                // free nodes recursively
    free(head);
}
```

The first argument to the function is advanced one by one until it reaches
the last node of the matched sequence. Then the function returns to the caller
stepping back to the first node of the matched sequence, while freeing the
nodes.
Here is the updated full code including the modification of `edit` function
to return the head of the edited list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LinkedNode {
    char data;
    struct LinkedNode *next;
} LinkedNode;

/*
 * append the node with data at the end of the list
 */
void append(LinkedNode *head, char data)
{
    LinkedNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    LinkedNode *temp = head;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newNode;
}

/*
 * dump the data of the list
 */
void dump(LinkedNode *head)
{
    for (head = head->next; head != NULL; head = head->next) {
        printf("%c ", head->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*
 * compare characters complementarily
 * return 1 for matching pairs as A<=>T or C<=>G
 */
int compcomp(char a, char b)
{
    if ((a == 'A' && b == 'T') || (a == 'T' && b == 'A')
        || (a == 'C' && b == 'G') || (a == 'G' && b == 'C'))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

/*
 * return the pointer to the last node if the subsequences match complementarily
 */
LinkedNode *match(LinkedNode *head, LinkedNode *bond)
{
    for (; head != NULL; head = head->next, bond = bond->next) {
        if (! compcomp(head->data, bond->data)) {
            return NULL;
        } else if (bond->next == NULL) {
            return head;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

/*
 * free skipped nodes
 */
void freenodes(LinkedNode *head, LinkedNode *tail)
{
    if (head->next == tail) {                   // the last node to remove
        // printf("> %c\n", head->data);        // for debugging
        free(head);
        return;
    }
    freenodes(head->next, tail);                // free nodes recursively
    // printf("> %c\n", head->data);            // for debugging
    free(head);
}

/*
 * search "head" for the sequence of complementary of "bond". If matched,
 * the matched portion is skipped and skipped nodes are freed
 */
LinkedNode *edit(LinkedNode *head, LinkedNode *bond)
{
    LinkedNode *matched;                        // last node of matched sequence
    LinkedNode *matchednext;
    LinkedNode *tmp;                            // copy of head to traverse the list

    for (tmp = head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next) {
        if ((matched = match(tmp->next, bond->next))) {
            matchednext = matched->next;        // backup matched->next
            freenodes(tmp->next, matched->next);
            tmp->next = matchednext;            // skip matched sequence
        }
    }

    return head;
}

int main()
{
    char dna_orig[] = "ACGTAGACGTTCTA";
    char dna_bond[] = "GCA";
    int i;

    // generate list of original sequence
    LinkedNode *head = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
    head->next = NULL;
    for (i = 0; dna_orig[i] != 0; i++) {
        append(head, dna_orig[i]);
    }

    // generate list of bonding sequence
    LinkedNode *bond = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
    bond->next = NULL;
    for (i = 0; dna_bond[i] != 0; i++) {
        append(bond, dna_bond[i]);
    }

    // edit the original sequence and see the result
    dump(edit(head, bond));

    return 0;
}
```

BTW you can omit `#include <stdio.h>` by dropping `printf()` and `fprintf()` functions which are used just for the reporting purpose.

**[EDIT2]**
The main difference between your code and mine is the data structure of
the linked list. The `head` of my list has empty data and is the *entrance*
to the first node, while your `dna_original` directly starts with the node
which contains the data. Same with `bond` and `sequencia`.
Both have its own advantages but we cannot mix them.
Then please modify your `editar_dna` as:

```
LinkedNode *editar_dna(LinkedNode *dna_original, LinkedNode *seq_edicao){
    LinkedNode *matched, *matchednext, *tmp;

    for (tmp = dna_original; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next) {
        if ((matched = match(tmp->next, seq_edicao))) {
            matchednext = matched->next;
            liberar_nos(tmp->next, matched->next);
            tmp->next = matchednext;
        }
    }

    return dna_original;
}
```

changing `seq_edicao->next` to `seq_edicao` in `match()` function. Then It will output `A A A`.
The potential problem of your data structure is we cannot remove
the starting subsequence such as: `"CGTACGTA"`. It is technically
possible to fix but may require additional huge modifications.

Now you have three options:

1. Neglect the edge case starting with matched subsequence.
2. Modify the linked list structure (easy but I'm not sure if it is acceptable.)
3. Find a countermeasure keeping current data structure.

It's up to you. :)

**[EDIT3]**
Here is the version applying option 3 (w/o the modification of main) to your code (FYI):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LinkedNode LinkedNode;
struct LinkedNode {
   char data;
   LinkedNode *next;
};

void imprimir1(LinkedNode *inicio){
    if(inicio == NULL){
    return;
    }

    printf("%c", inicio->data);
    if (inicio->next!=NULL) printf(" ");
    else printf("\n");
    imprimir1(inicio->next);
    return;
}

void liberar_lista(LinkedNode *inicio){
    if(inicio == NULL) return;
    liberar_lista(inicio->next);
    free(inicio);
}

LinkedNode *inserir_final_r(LinkedNode *inicio, char valor) {
    if (inicio == NULL) {
        LinkedNode *novo = malloc(sizeof(LinkedNode));
        if (novo == NULL) return inicio;
        novo->data = valor;
        novo->next = NULL;
        return novo;
    }
    inicio->next = inserir_final_r(inicio->next, valor);
    return inicio;
}

void liberar_nos(LinkedNode *head, LinkedNode *tail) {
    if (head == tail) {
        return;
    }
    liberar_nos(head->next, tail);
    free(head);
}

int compare(char a, char b) {
    if ((a == 'A' && b == 'T') || (a == 'T' && b == 'A')
        || (a == 'C' && b == 'G') || (a == 'G' && b == 'C'))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

LinkedNode *match(LinkedNode *head, LinkedNode *bond) {
    for (; head != NULL; head = head->next, bond = bond->next) {
        if (! compare(head->data, bond->data)) {
            return NULL;
        } else if (bond->next == NULL) {
            return head;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

LinkedNode *editar_dna(LinkedNode *dna_original, LinkedNode *seq_edicao){
    LinkedNode *matched, *matchednext, *tmp;

    // remove leading matched subsequence(s) as a preproces
    while ((matched = match(dna_original, seq_edicao))) {
        matchednext = matched->next;
        liberar_nos(dna_original->next, matched->next); // note we cannot free the 1st node
        dna_original->data = matchednext->data;
        dna_original->next = matchednext->next;
        liberar_nos(matchednext, matchednext->next);    // free the copied node which is no longer used
    }
/*
    for (tmp = dna_original; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next) {
        if ((matched = match(tmp->next, seq_edicao))) {
            matchednext = matched->next;
            liberar_nos(tmp->next, matched->next);
            tmp->next = matchednext;
        }
    }
*/
    for (tmp = dna_original; tmp != NULL; ) {
        if ((matched = match(tmp->next, seq_edicao))) {
            matchednext = matched->next;
            liberar_nos(tmp->next, matched->next);
            tmp->next = matchednext;                    // skip matched sequence
        } else {
            tmp = tmp->next;                            // proceed to next node
        }
    }

    return dna_original;
}

int main(){

    //Creating empty nodes
    LinkedNode *dna_original = NULL;
    LinkedNode *sequencia = NULL;

    //Populating test data into the original sequence
//    dna_original = inserir_final_r(dna_original, 'A');        // dropped just for the test
    dna_original = inserir_final_r(dna_original, 'C');
    dna_original = inserir_final_r(dna_original, 'G');
    dna_original = inserir_final_r(dna_original, 'T');
    dna_original = inserir_final_r(dna_original, 'C');
    dna_original = inserir_final_r(dna_original, 'G');
    dna_original = inserir_final_r(dna_original, 'T');
    dna_original = inserir_final_r(dna_original, 'A');
    dna_original = inserir_final_r(dna_original, 'C');
    dna_original = inserir_final_r(dna_original, 'G');
    dna_original = inserir_final_r(dna_original, 'T');
    dna_original = inserir_final_r(dna_original, 'A');

    //Populating test data into the second sequence
    sequencia = inserir_final_r(sequencia, 'G');
    sequencia = inserir_final_r(sequencia, 'C');
    sequencia = inserir_final_r(sequencia, 'A');

    //Printing the original sequence before change
    imprimir1(dna_original);

    //Changing the sequence
    editar_dna(dna_original, sequencia);

    //Printing the original sequence after change
    imprimir1(dna_original);

    //Freeing allocated memory
    liberar_lista(dna_original);
    liberar_lista(sequencia);

    return 0;
}
```

Please note the initialization of the list in main() is modified for the debugging and demonstration purpose.

Comment: I really appreciate your contribution. However, my main issue is that I must return to the main function the head of the new formed linked list. I've tried to replicate your code, but I'm struggling with finding a way of transversing the list without changing the main head that I must return.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. Please let me clarify the requirement. 1) To return the head of the newly created and edited linked list in main. 2) The original list should not be modified. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Question 1) Correct. Question 2) No. The original is the one that should be modified. Only two arguments must be passed from main to the function: the head of the original dna sequence and the head of the second sequence (as previously stated). I must only return the head of the original sequence after edit.

Comment: Got the code working! However, I still have to free those skipped nodes. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Now I think I've understood the requirements. I've updated the code applying: 1) edit function to return the head of the edited list. 2) edit function to free skipped nodes. 3) the second argument to the edit function is now the head of the second sequence itself, not the complementary one. I hope it will work.

Comment: It is almost near perfection. Unfortunately I mustn't use malloc for this specific exercise. The operation should only use the nodes that have already been allocated, but it is still allowed to use the free function for freeing memory.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt review. Now I've updated the code dropping `gencomp()` function which internally uses `malloc()`. The remaining `malloc()`s are to generate the list and will not be used for the exercise which assumes the lists are given. How about now?

Comment: For some reason now the first letter of the sequence that has to be removed is being ignored by the algorithm. However, this is happening only with my code. And the only difference between my code to yours is that my main() has different functions to dump and populate both linked lists, but I am totally sure that this has nothing to do with these as it was working fine before. To be honest I've got no idea what could it be, but we're getting real close. Would you mind taking a look at my current code? Here's the link: https://pastebin.com/xKyBKB3Z

Comment: I've updated my answer with the modified function. It will solve the current problem but We may need another modifications. BR.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243130/discussion-between-joc-and-tshiono).

Comment: A note for any future readers: @tshiono's edit 3 made it all along the way! Fully working and functional. Thank you for your amazing effort! :-)

Answer (score 1):

From the title and discussion I'm assuming that applying the edit should mutate the input list by removing matched subsequences. If the first node of the list is removed, you'll need to return a pointer to some later node. Otherwise the first node is returned.

The naive way to handle the two cases is with specific checks. But, there's a well-known pattern for handling both cases as one. It's pre-pending a "dummy" head node temporarily, which is never removed. Rather than try to explain further, I'll append code. See `apply_edit`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node_s {
  struct node_s *next;
  char base;
} Node;

void print(Node *seq) {
  for (Node *p = seq; p; p = p->next) printf("%c", p->base);
  printf("\n");
}

bool base_match(char x, char y) {
  switch (x) {
    case 'A': return y == 'T';
    case 'C': return y == 'G';
    case 'G': return y == 'C';
    case 'T': return y == 'A';
  }
  exit(42); // input error
}

// If the prefix of seq is as given, return the following seq node, else seq.
Node *remove_prefix(Node *prefix, Node *seq) {
  Node *p, *s;
  for (p = prefix, s = seq; p && s; p = p->next, s = s->next)
    if (!base_match(p->base, s->base))
      return seq;
  return p ? seq : s;
}

Node *apply_edit(Node *edit, Node *seq) {
  Node head[1] = {{ seq }};
  for (Node *p = head; p && p->next; ) {
    Node *next = remove_prefix(edit, p->next);
    if (next == p->next) p = next;  // No match; advance one.
    else p->next = next;  // Remove the match; don't advance.
  }
  return head->next;
}

Node *build_seq(char *gene) {
  Node *seq = NULL;
  for (int i = strlen(gene) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    node->base = gene[i];
    node->next = seq;
    seq = node;
  }
  return seq;
}

int main(void) {
  // Provided test case. Expect AAGATCTA.
  print(apply_edit(build_seq("GCA"), build_seq("ACGTAGACGTTCTA")));
  // Remove from head. Expect A.
  print(apply_edit(build_seq("GCA"), build_seq("CGTA")));
  // Remove from tail. Expect A.
  print(apply_edit(build_seq("GCA"), build_seq("ACGT")));
  // Incomplete match at tail. Expect ACG
  print(apply_edit(build_seq("GCA"), build_seq("ACG")));
  // Remove all. Expect empty string.
  print(apply_edit(build_seq("GCA"), build_seq("CGTCGT")));
  // Remove creates new match, which is ignored. Expect CGT.
  print(apply_edit(build_seq("GCA"), build_seq("CCGTGT")));

  return 0;
}
```

Though it makes for code that's a bit harder to read, you can inline the helper function where it's called in `apply_edit` and get something very concise:

```
Node *apply_edit(Node *edit, Node *seq) {
  Node *e, *s, head[1] = {{ seq }};
  for (Node *p = head; p && p->next; ) {
    for (e = edit, s = p->next; e && s; e = e->next, s = s->next)
      if (!base_match(e->base, s->base)) break;
    if (e) p = s;  // No match; advance one.
    else p->next = s;  // Remove the match; don't advance.
  }
  return head->next;
}
```

I'll also point out that traversing lists with recursion is something you wouldn't do in production code. While a good compiler with optimizations turned up will convert tail recursion (like yours) into iteration, it can be a finicky optimization ... as in the compiler will skip it under non-obvious circumstances. If that happens, your program needs stack space proportional to the length of lists you're traversing, while an iterative code will run fine in one stack frame. That's a big deal if your program needs to be reliable.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks a lot, Gene! There's one small issue: I still need to free those "skipped" nodes. Got any ideas?

Comment: Also, I'm getting the following error when I adapt it into my code:

Warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'char' with an expression of type 'LinkedNode *' (aka 'struct LinkedNode *') [-Wint-conversion]
LinkedNode head[1] = {{ seq }}
                                        ^~~
Note: had to remove <stdbool.h> since the exercise asks me to avoid any headers besides stdlib.h. I've kept <stdio.h> for printing but will also have to remove it when submitting the exercise, keeping only <stdlib.h>.

Comment: @JOC Freeing the nodes at the point where they're cut out of the original sequence is pretty basic stuff.  I'll let you work that out.  `int` can always be used in place of `bool`, but it's bad practice.  You could just add `typedef int bool;`, which is more-or-less what `stdbool.h` does. There's no way to explain the error without seeing your code.